# Is there a way to set 'expires' option in Sequelize timestamps just like Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, sequelize.js

```
const sequelize = require("../config/sequelize");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const Token = sequelize.define('token', {
    token: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        expires: 43200
    }
})
```

Can I add expires option like in the above code in Sequelize?

Comment: That is a feature of the underlying database, not Mongoose itself. What database are you planning on using with Sequelize?

Comment: I am planning to use Mysql database with Sequelize.

Comment: I don't think MySQL has similar functionality built-in. But you might be able to create it yourself using their [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But how can I go about creating it myself?

Comment: you can use [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) which will perform delete query like expires at certain time setted by you

Answer (score 1):

@ayindesamuel why don't you create the tokenExpires key directly inside your sequelize model? Also, including a third object allows you to turn on timestamps (createdAt and updatedAt) these columns will be automatically added by sequelize. So you don't have to manually create the Key.

```
const sequelize = require("../config/sequelize");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const Token = sequelize.define('token', {
    token: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    tokenExpires : {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Date.now() +  43200
    }
}, { timestamps : true })
```

Comment: ERROR: Invalid default value for tokenExpires